# Android: Width of ImageView not changing from SeekBar listener

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple Android app, in which the user can drag a `SeekBar` to the left to reveal less of an image, and right to reveal more of an image. This is accomplished through attaching a listener to the `SeekBar`, in which the width of the ImageView is changed proportionally to the `SeekBar`'s progress. The **problem** is that no matter what position the slider is in, the width of the ImageView **remains the same**, as shown in the screenshots below:

Progress = 0%:

[image]

Progress = 100%

[image]

This seems strange, considering that in the `SeekBar`'s listener, when I output the value I am setting the `ImageView` width to, that value is correct.

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/simpleSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#0000FF">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="300px"
            android:layout_width="300px"
            android:src="@drawable/android"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:id="@+id/iv"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.changingimageviewwidth2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);

        SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                iv.getLayoutParams().width = 300 * progress/100;
                System.out.println(300 * progress/100);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //write custom code to on start progress
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note**: The image is **NOT supposed to be resized** when the slider is moved.

Comment: I have created something for you. Please check video and let me how it looks -> https://streamable.com/1eirol

Comment: @HarisDautović This looks perfect! If you could post your corresponding code, I'll definitely accept your answer and reward the bounty.

Comment: Ok Thanks, also, I'll upload functional example on github so you can pull the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with an additional `View` on top of the layout hierarchy with the same size as `ImageView`. We dynamically change the top View `startMargin` to have an image revealing/hiding effect.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv);
        final View dynamicView = ((View) findViewById(R.id.dynamicView));
        final SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) dynamicView.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMarginStart(imageView.getWidth() * progress / 100);
                dynamicView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/simpleSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/owl"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dynamicView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**: https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/tree/q_68375499

**Additional:**

- Instead of **px** use **dp** in layouts
- My suggestion is to switch to Kotlin
- ConstraintLayout is a better option if you want to have better performance and avoid nested views

**EDIT:**
I was not happy with the first solution and did a small research. **A better way is to do it using ImageView overlay**.

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv);
        final SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar);

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                addOverlay(R.drawable.overlay, imageView, imageView.getWidth() * progress / 100);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

        // Initial overlay
        imageView.post(() -> addOverlay(R.drawable.overlay, imageView, 0));
    }

    private void addOverlay(int resourceId, ImageView imageView, int startMargin) {
        imageView.getOverlay().clear();
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), resourceId, null);
        drawable.setBounds(new Rect(startMargin, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight()));
        imageView.getOverlay().add(drawable);
    }
}
```

**res->drawable-overlay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</layer-list>
```

**res->layout->activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/simpleSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/owl"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**: https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/commits/q_68375499_v2

**EDIT:** Final solution and what Adam actually wanted to achieve is:

[image]

**Code:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/tree/q_68375499_v3

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to solve this problem without using a separate View or Overlay on top of the ImageView? The reason is that I am trying to create an image comparison app with another image below the current image, such that when you reveal less of the current image, more of the below image shows. If a separate View or Overlay is on top of the ImageView, that would block out both the current and the bottom image.

Comment: @AdamLee Using the second solution I have provided each ImageView can have separated logic for ImageView overlay.

Comment: True, each ImageView can have separated logic for the ImageView overlay, but the issue is that I want to place two ImageViews on top of each other. The SeekBar is for the top ImageView, and when the SeekBar is dragged to the left or right, less and more of the ImageView is shown, respectively, which is what is expected. However, sincethe Overlay is white, even though I didn't put any Overlay logic on the bottom ImageView, the top ImageView's white Overlay covers both the top and the bottom image. I'm aiming for this UI: https://www.diffchecker.com/image-diff/ or https://imgur.com/a/lFOyEWc

Comment: This is the best example of the UI I am aiming for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXvM9.jpg

Comment: @AdamLee I have exactly what you need. Do you still need this? Here is how it looks -> https://streamable.com/hxycsg

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely perfect and what I need :D. If you could update your answer, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                iv.getLayoutParams().width = 300 * progress/100;
                iv.drawableStateChanged(); //<--- You need to redraw it after you change it.
                System.out.println(300 * progress/100);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                iv.getLayoutParams().width = 200 * progress;
                iv.getLayoutParams().height= 200 * progress;
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //write custom code to on start progress
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
```